# Retrieve data from Wordpress for mobile version of the site

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I need to create a mobile version of a Wordpress website, but I do not plan on using Wordpress to develop it (I want to build it from JQuery Mobile in pure HTML/CSS/JS).

How can I fetch content from a "blog" page on the Wordpress web and show it on my mobile webiste? The mobile version of the Wordpress is basically a very simplified version of the website. If I am not clear don't hesitate to question me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp/wp-config.php');

$id = 0; //Your ID here
$post = get_page($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;


?>
```

Assign the $id variable with the post to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build a responsive site that works everywhere?